# GitHub Actions - Notifications for scheduled cron jobs

Tags: scheduled-tasks, github-actions

Is it possible to get email or Slack notifications for Workflow scheduled Cron jobs?

Comment: Why not adding a step to the workflow jobs to send an email or notification everytime the workflow is executed?

Comment: @GuiFalourd would this be the step required?
'- name: Send mail
  uses: dawidd6/action-send-mail@v3
  with:'

Comment: It is an option, yes. Other actions [on the Github marketplace](https://github.com/marketplace?type=actions&query=send+email+) can also be useful depending  on what (and how) you want to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom app in Slack, with an incoming webhook, and add a step to your workflow to post a JSON message to that webhook URL.

**In Slack**

1. Start by creating a new Slack app, at https://api.slack.com/apps?new_app=1
2. Activate the Incoming Webhooks feature
3. Add a new webhook URL, which may need to be approved by an administrator of your workspace
4. Add a new webhook to your workspace, selecting a channel for the post to be sent to
5. Copy the webhook URL

**In GitHub**

1. Go to your repository settings, and add an Actions secret named `SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL` with the value being the URL copied from Slack

**In the Actions workflow**

1. Add a new step to your workflow:

   ```yaml
   -
   name: Notify Slack
   run: |
     curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data \
       '{"username": "GitHub Actions robot", "icon_emoji": ":robot_face:", "text": "GitHub Actions workflow completed"}' \
       ${SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL}
   ```